# How can I get rid of white space at the top of a HTML page on Dash?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I'm creating a 'blog' page on Dash (learning with General Assembly), and there's some white space at the top of the page that I can't seem to get rid of? This is the code I've used for the header:

```
 header {
      text-align: center;
      background: linear-gradient(#f9eeaa, #f9d6aa);
      background-size: cover;
      color: #f78;
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image: 1]

Comment: Please, provide all the HTML code of the page, as well as the CSS it uses. You gave us too few details. If you can, provide also a scrennshot that shows the issue.

Comment: hey I've added a screenshot does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you provided I would recomend the following css attributes.

```
 *{margin:0;padding:0;} body {margin: 0;} header {margin: 0; top:0;}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correct than you could try to add:
margin: 0;